# Android - How to set Device input - either touchscreen or mouse

Tags: android, touch, kernel, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm currently compiling for Android for a device and have recently upped the ICS build. I'm facing an issue with the touch. The touch controller is on but the screen is treated like a track pad for mouse input with a cursor appearing over the screen. How do I make the touchscreen input be used as a touch screen and not as a mouse input.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th issue here was with the IDC file. IDC = Input Device Configuration file. I had borrowed the touch driver from a different device with the same hardware, but I hadn't taken the idc file for this change.

Adding this to the product config file fixed it for me.